$u,v$ are unit vectors. What is the value of max $|u^TAv|$
Suppose $u,v\in \mathbb{R}^n,A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $u,v$ are unit vectors. The goal is to get the value $\max_{u,v}$ $|u^TAv|$.
If $A$ is symmetric, then it can be diagonized. $|u^TAv|= \langle \sqrt{A}u,\sqrt{A}v\rangle \leq ||\sqrt{A}u||_2||\sqrt{A}v||_2\leq max\{|\lambda_1|,|\lambda_n|\}$, here $\lambda_i$ is $A$'s $i$-th largest eigenvalue. And if $u=v$ is the eigenvector, the maximal value can be achieved.
When $A$ is not symmetric, can we get any formula for $\max_{u,v}$ $|u^TAv|$? For example, $A$ may not have eigenvalues, so is there any relationship with the eigenvalues of $AA^T$?

Is it ok to express the answer in terms of the operator norm of $A$ or its singular values? Also it should be $|u^T A v|$, not $|u A v^T|$.

@Adayah Ok. And I have fixed the error.

Do you want the max as $u,v$ vary over all unit vectors?

The maximum is equal  $|A|$ which can be expressed as the square root of the maximal eigenvalue of $A^TA$ or $AA^T$ as the eigenvalues of these two matrices coincide.

@GEdgar Right,$u,v$ vary and $A$ is fixed

I believe this is called the operator norm of $A$.

By the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have
$$|\langle x,y\rangle |\le \|x\|\,\|y\|$$ and the equality occurs iff $x$ and $y$ are parallel. Fix $u,$ $\|u\|=1$ such that $Au\neq 0.$ Let $\|v\|=1.$ Then $$|\langle Au, v\rangle |\le \|Au\|$$ and the equality occurs when $v=\|Au\|^{-1}Au.$  Therefore
$$m:=\max_{\|u\|=\|v\|=1}|\langle Au,v\rangle=\max_{\|u\|=1} \|Au\|$$ We have
$\|Au\|^2=\langle A^TAu,u\rangle.$ Hence $m^2=\displaystyle\max_{\|u\|=1}\langle A^TAu,u\rangle .$ The matrix $A^TA$ is symmetric and its eigenvalues are nonnegative. Let $\lambda$ be the largest eigenvalue of $A^TA$ and $u_\lambda$ the corresponding unit eigenvector. Then $m^2\ge \langle A^TAu_\lambda,u_\lambda \rangle =\lambda.$ The converse inequality follows from the property that $A^TA$ can be diagonalized and its  eigenvectors are orthogonal to each other. Hence $m=\sqrt{\lambda}.$
The nonzero eigenvalues of $A^TA$ and $AA^T$ coincide, so do their maximal eigenvalues. Thus $m$ is equal to the square root of the maximal eigenvalue of $AA^T.$

Set the Lagrangian $L(s,t,u,v) = s(u^\intercal u - 1) + t (v^\intercal v - 1) + (u^\intercal A v)^2.$ Then $\partial_u L = 2su + 2 (u^\intercal A v) Av$ and $\partial_v L = 2tv + 2(u^\intercal A v) A^\intercal u.$ Assume $u^\intercal A v \neq 0$ (this is a valid assumption since we are after a maximum and $u^\intercal A v = 0$ for all $u,v$ unitary will imply $A = 0$). Since $\partial_u L = \partial_v L = 0,$ we must have $A^\intercal u = \lambda v$ and $A v = \mu u$ for some (nonzero) scalars $\lambda$ and $\mu.$ Thus, we reach $AA^\intercal u = \lambda \mu u$ and $A^\intercal A v = \lambda \mu v.$ Therefore, $u$ and $v$ are eigenvectors, corresponding to the same eigenvalue, of $AA^\intercal$ and $A^\intercal A$, respectively (it is well-known that $AA^\intercal$ and $A^\intercal A$ have the same non-negative eigenvalues). Furthermore, the equations $A^\intercal u = \lambda v$ and $Av = \mu u$ imply $u^\intercal A v = \lambda = \mu$ since $u^\intercal u = v^\intercal v = 1.$ Thus, $(u^\intercal A v) = \lambda^2$ is the eigenvalue of $A^\intercal A$ and $AA^\intercal$ common to $u$ and $v.$ We must therefore maximise said eigenvalue and we obtain a maximum this way. The maximum is guaranteed from the fact that $u^\intercal u = 1$ and $v^\intercal v = 1$ define a compact set on the $(u,v)$ space.
In conclusion, $\max (u^\intercal A v)^2$ subject to $\|u\| = \|v\| = 1$ equals $\lambda_\max(A^\intercal A) = \lambda_\max(AA^\intercal) > 0$ unless $A = 0.$ Therefore, the maximum of $|u^\intercal A v|$ equals $\sqrt{\lambda_\max(A^\intercal A)} = \sqrt{\lambda_\max(AA^\intercal)}.$

Fun fact, the same technique shows the maximum of $x^\intercal Q x$ subject to $|x| = 1$ equals $\lambda_\max(Q)$ and since each function $Q \mapsto x^\intercal Q x$ is linear, it turns out that $f(Q) = \lambda_\max(Q)$ is a convex function (being the supremum over $x$ of linear functions). Since $\lambda_\max(-Q) = -\lambda_\min(Q)$ we have that $Q \mapsto \lambda_\min(Q)$ is concave...
